# python: make a class object iterable

Tags: python, list, object, iterable, class-method

Here is what i am trying to do:

i created a classmethod that returns either an object of `dict` if not params are added to this method or an object made of list of dicts if any params are added, as code below:

```
@classmethod
def make_attr(cls, **kwargs):
    """
    code: do something, generate either a tuple 
    """ 
    if :
        data = {}
        """
        add k, v in data
        """
        return cls(**data)
    else:
        data = []
        for k, v in kwargs.items():
            _d = {}
            _d[k] = v
            data.append(_d)
        return cls(*data)
```

Code as above, and the problem i met is if the classmethod returns object of dict, i can use `object.attr` to get its value, but if the classmethod returns objects of list, i find no way to unpack it or get its attribute or value, such as:

```
>> result = Class.make_attr(login_name="test")
>> print("age: ", result.age)
>> age: 25

>> result = Class.make_attr()
>> print(result)
>> <model._class.Class object at 0x104020358>

>> for i in result:
>>     print(i)
>> TypeError: 'Class' object is not iterable
```

So, how can i make this object iterable?

Comment: @ducminh thanks for help, I just look over that similar question and find out my solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally find a way to solve the problem, by adding built-in methods in my class:

```
class Class:
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.start = 0
        self.end = args

    def __iter__(self):
        return self

    def __next__(self):
        if self.start >= len(self.end):
            raise StopIteration
        else:
            self.start += 1
            return self.end[self.start-1]
```

again, thanks @ducminh